# htaccess rewrite, *.OldDomain.com to *.NewDomain.com with directory changes (301 redirect)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

htaccess rewrite,   *.olddomain.com  to *.newdomain.com with directory changes

There are about 50 subdomains, so I write for each subdomain, which can redirect every page  of old site to the new site:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain1\.olddomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://subdomain1.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain2\.olddomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://subdomain2.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
 ... 
 ...  
  ... 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain50\.olddomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://subdomain50.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]    

 <Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

---

The code above works for me,

but I have another things that need to rewrite too at the same time,

1

```
*.olddomain.com/ca/abd/  (there will be  no pages or anything at the end of / )
*.olddomain.com/ca/sdf/
*.olddomain.com/ca/dfsd/
*.olddomain.com/ca/sdfsd/
*.olddomain.com/ca/sdfsd/
*.olddomain.com/ca/sdfa/
...
...
```

need to be redirected to to

```
*.newdomain.com/t/abd/    (there will be  no pages or anything at the end of / )
*.newdomain.com/t/sdf/
*.newdomain.com/t/dfsd/
*.newdomain.com/t/sdfsd/
*.newdomain.com/t/sdfsd/
*.newdomain.com/t/sdfa/
```

2

```
*.olddomain.com/ca/abd/sdfa/
*.olddomain.com/ca/abd/adfa/
*.olddomain.com/ca/abd/adfadf/
*.olddomain.com/ca/abd/adfadf/
*.olddomain.com/ca/abd/adfads/
...
```

to

```
*.newdomain.com/t/abd/sdfa/
*.newdomain.com/t/abd/adfa/
*.newdomain.com/t/abd/adfadf/
*.newdomain.com/t/abd/adfadf/
*.newdomain.com/t/abd/adfads/
```

'ca' become   't', and there are a lot of  categories  that follow this pattern, I don't mind if the code is long at all, but how can I  make them work in a htaccess file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here we go :)

```
# BEGIN Redirect Code
RewriteEngine On
# all urls with ca - main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ca
RewriteRule ^ca/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/t/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# all urls without ca - main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# all urls with ca - sub domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ca/(.*)$ http://%1.newdomain.com/t/$1 [R=301,L]

# all urls without ca - sub domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# END Redirect Code
```

You can contact me if you have any specific requirement here:
https://www.fiverr.com/ansarahmed